# Does the Torah prohibition to not add or subtract from the mitzvot also apply to the Oral Torah?

Tags: halacha, oral-torah, bal-tosif-no-adding

Since it says in the Torah to not add or subtract from the mitzvot so does that also apply to the Oral Torah.

"Do not add or subtract from the mitzvot." (Deut. 4:2)

Answer (score 4):

It does apply: you cannot add or subtract from the Oral Torah. (Rambam [Koteret to Hilkhot Mamrim](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e300.htm), [Sefer HaChinukh 454](http://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.454.1?lang=bi))

Comment: Mishna in Sanhedrin 5 totafot