# PTIJ: Is there any Jewish/Talmudic literature which discusses Mi Yodeya guidelines?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I have read ample sections of the Talmud, but I have never come across any laws which can assist me with my interactions on Mi Yodeya - a site dedicated to Jewish law. Is there any Talmud which can help me with this?

Note: I ask particularity concerning the cannon of Jewish law and literature, not concerning Mi Yodeya, otherwise that would belong on Meta, Duh.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I copied a manuscript in shorthand from someone who had the last surviving copy, but he would not allow me to remove it from his domain. This is only a small section of the printed version. I have translated accordingly.

## *מסכת יודעין*

משנה: כיצד שואלין את היודעין רבי דובל אומר שואלין על התורה הנביאים וכתובים רבי יצחק אומר אף על ספרים החיצונים אמר לו רבי דובל לא אם אמרת על ספרים החיצונים אין לדבר סוף רבי משהה העיד על מוניכא שבקשה להוציא כל דברי ספרים החיצונים וצוה לה רבי דובל ואמר לה בכל יום דנין את הזכאי ואת חיב על ידי ויוט ואין נותנין הכלל על ספרים החיצונים שנאמר (קבלת יב) בני וגו׳ עשות ספרים הרבה:

MISHNAH: HOW DO WE ASK THE YODEYANS? REBBI DOUBLE SAYS: ON THE TORAH, NEVI’IM AND KESUVIM. REBBI YITZCHAK SAYS: EVEN ON THE OUTER BOOKS. REBBI DOUBLE SAID TO HIM: NO, IF YOU HAVE SAID ON THE OUTER BOOKS, THERE WILL BE NO LIMIT TO THIS. REBBI MSH TESTIFIED ABOUT MONICA WHO WISHED TO REMOVE ALL THE OUTER BOOKS, AND REBBI DOUBLE COMMANDED HER AND SAID TO HER: EVERY DAY WE JUDGE THE INNOCENT AND THE GUILTY THROUGH THE VOTE, BUT WE DO NOT PRESENT GENERAL RULES ON THE OUTER BOOKS, AS IT SAYS (KOHELETH 12) MY SON, MAKE MANY BOOKS

גמרא: למה לי למתני כיצד שואלין את היודעין ליתני כיצד שואלין קמ״ל טעמא דשואלין את היודעין הא לאו הכי שואלין אף על העכו״ם פשיטא הקמ״ל דהשתא הוא דאקרי יודעין הא נפק מדוכתיה לדוכתא אחרינא התם נמי איקרי יודעין קמ״ל:

Why do I need to teach ‘how do we ask the Yodeyans’, He should teach ‘how do we ask’. This comes to tell us the reason [we are restricted in asking] is because we are asking the Yodeyans. Were it not so, we would even be able to ask about other religions. That is obvious! No, this come to tell us that it is now whence [a Yodeyan] is called Yodeyan. If he went out from his website to another website, there would he still be called a Yodeyan? This indeed comes to tell us [that he would not].

רבי דובל אומר וכו: מאי טעמיה דרבי דובל כדתנן אמרו היודעין לא ירדו אבותינו למצרים אלא כדי לקבל את התורה ואם אין אנו מקיימין אותה מוטב לנו לעבוד אותם בפרך השתא דקאמר תורה שבכתב תורה שבעל פה מנא ליה מנא ליה כדקאמרן

REBBI DOUBLE SAYS ETC.: What is the reasoning of Rabbi Double? As we have learned in a Mishnah. The Yodeyans said: Our forefathers only descended into Egypt in order to accept to the Torah, and if we are not fulfilling it [properly] it would be better for us to serve them in hardship. Now that he is discussing the Written Torah, how does he know of the Oral Torah? How does he know of it? As we have [already] said!

אמר אלקס סבר רבי דובל מאי תורה בין תורה שבעל פה בין תורה שבכתב אי הכי הנביאים וכתובים למה לי לתני תורה ואנא ידענא תורה שבכתב והנביאים וכתובים בכלל צריכא כיון דתורה שבעל פה בכלל לא ניחא ליה לתנא למתני ביה תרתי ולתני תורה שבכתב ותורה שבעל פה וליליף הנביאים וכתובים מיניה חד מן חד יליף תרי מן חד לא יליף:

Alex said: Rabbi Double thought, what is Torah [referring to]? Both the Written and Oral Torahs. If [that is] so, why do I need ‘the Nevi’im and Ketuvim’? He should teach ‘Torah’ and I will know that the Written Torah and the Nevi’im and Ketuvim are included [in that word]. It is needed. Since the Oral Torah is included, it does not please the Tanna to teach two items [in one]. And so let him teach ‘the Written and Oral Torah’ and let him derive ‘the Nevi’im and Ketuvim’ from it. He will derive one from one, but not two from one.

אמר רב שלום אלקס איהו קמייתא דהדר לא ואמאי נפק קמייתא בתר דנחת למהוי אלימא מן בין חבריא שדרו גזירפטי האי מבני חילא למיהב ליה תלת מאה רבוא דהבא ולא ליהדר טפי לבי היודעין ולא קבלה מיניה בתר הכי נפק קלא מן הרמנא דמלכא ארישיה למקטל ביה ערק וסבר מטמר נפשיה אזל טשא בי מדרשא ואוקי התם ויליף וגריס להו אורייתא יומא חדא אידכר האי עלמא דבי יודעין וסבר למימר אנא לית אנא יכיל למהדר בהו אלא אית לי גבאי האי גברא רבא ואיהו צורבא מרבנן ונפק אלקס בתרייתא תותי שמיה דידיה דקמייתא:

Rav Shalom said: Is Alex the first one which has [now] returned? No [he is not]. And [then] why did the first one leave? After he had settled to be the superior among his colleagues, the royal officers sent a soldier [to Alex] to give him [by way of bribery] three million golden pieces in order so that he shall never return again. [However, Alex] did not accept it from him. After this [incident], an official proclamation went out from the king’s authority upon [Alex’s] head, to kill him. [Alex then] fled, and figured that he must hide himself. He went and hid out in the study hall, and established [himself] there, and he learned and taught them Torah [there]. One day, he recalled upon the world of Mi Yodeya, and he thought to say, I am unable to return to them. However, there is a great man by my locale, and he is a young scholar among the Rabbis [and so Alex sent him]. So, the second Alex went out under the username of the first.

תניא אלו הן ספרים החיצונים ספרי לעז ספרי מדינת ישראל ספרי מומרים בעי רב גרשון האי דקאמר רבי דובל אין לדבר סוף הא קחזינן דאיכא אמר ליה רבות אימא סיפא אין נותנין הכלל על ספרים החיצונים אלמא הדר ביה רבי דובל:

We have learnt in a Baraita: These are the outer books, books of secular topics, books of the State of Israel and books of renegade Jews. Rav Gershon asked: This which Rabbi Double is saying ‘there will be no limit to this’, we see that there is [a limit]! Rabot said [to Rav Gershon], say from the ending [of the Mishnah], ‘but we do not present general rules on the outer books’. Therefore, Rabbi Double retracted [his opinion].

דרש עמם בר בלאח כתיב (אסתר א) וישלח ספרים וכתיב (אסתר ט) וישלח ספרים מה הכא ספרים ואל עם ועם כלשונו אף התם ספרים אל כל היהודים לומר לך דהלכה כרבי יצחק ולא יחסר מעם היהודים:

M bar Bloch expounded: it is written (Esther 1) ‘And he sent books’ and it says (Esther 9) ‘And he sent books’. Just as here [in the first verse, it is referring to] books, and to each nation according to their language, also there [in the second verse, it is referring to] books to the Jews. [This is in order] to teach you that the law follows Rabbi Yitzchak, and so that the Jew nation shall not be lacking [books].

בעי עאל מהו לדבר אבל לא לשאול מהו להשיב על הנשאלין מהו לתקן מהו להכשיר הפסול מהו להוציא בעל מום מהו לאסור הטריפה מהו לאסור המותר תיקו:

Al asked: What is [the law] to speak of [a prohibited item], but not to ask of it? What is [the law] to respond to the [prohibitively] asked? What is [the law] to edit [the prohibitively asked]? What is [the law] to make the prohibited into a permitted [question]? What is [the law] validate the invalidated? What is [the law] to delete a blemished [post]? What is [the law] to prohibit a spam [post]? What is [the law] to prohibit the permitted? Let [these questions] stand [unanswered].

ת״ר אין בין רבי דובל לרבי יצחק אלא שלשה דברים בלבד ואלו הן כינויי לעז שיחה גזולה וזמן קבלת התשובה והתנן רבי יצחק אומר אף ספרים החיצונים ואמרינן מאי ספרים החיצונים כל ספרים החיצונים אלמא איכא טובא בינייהו לא קשיא הא ספרא הא מילתא

The Rabbis taught [in a Braita]: There is no [difference] between Rabbi Double and Rabbi Yitzchak except three things, and these are they: jargons, plagiarism, and the time of answer acceptance. But we have learned in our Mishnah: Rabbi Yitzchak says: Even the outer books. And we say on this, what [does the Mishnah mean by] the outer books? [It means] all the outer books. So we see, there is indeed many [things] which they differ upon! This is not a problem. Here [in the Mishnah] is a book, here [in the Braita] is a thing.

קתני מיהת כינויי לעז שיחה גזולה וזמן קבלת התשובה כינויי לעז סברי רבנן למימר משלי העכו״ם נינהו עד שבא עמם בר בלאח מארץ רחוקה ואמר קבלה בידי אין כינויי לעז אלא דיבורי בני אדם וכל חרד לבו לא ידבר בהם שיחה גזולה ומי איכא דפליג עליה דרבי דובל אין רבי יואל בן קירא היא דאמר מה שיחה שאינה גזולה יש בה חוששין לספק גזולה מחמת הטבע ושרי שיחה גזולה דוודאי גזולה עאכ״ו דשרי

We have nonetheless taught of jargons, plagiarism, and the time of answer acceptance. Jargons: The Rabbis thought to say [that they are] gentile quips. Until, M bar Bloch came from a distant land and said: I have a tradition that Jargons are just simply local dialectal expressions. However, anyone whose heart is righteous shall [better] not speak of them. Plagiarism: Does anyone argue with Rabbi Double [concerning this matter]? Yes, it is Rabbi Joel ben Kera, who said: Just as unplagiarized [content still] has a concern of a doubt of plagiarism by dint of nature, [however,] it is [nonetheless] permitted. Plagiarism which has certainly been plagiarized, all the more so that it should be permitted!

מתיב אלקס ותסברא גזולה דספק נידוי ספק אינו נידוי מי אמרינן ליזיל ולשמתיה קמ״ל כל חרד לבו לא ידבר בהם וזמן קבלת התשובה כלל אמרו במרילנד כל תשובה שאין בה דרישה וחקירה תולין לא מקבלין ולא מוחקין אמר שמואל הא נקטנין זמן קבלת התשובה מעת לעת כפולה

Alex questioned this: Is that at all logical? Plagiarized [content] which has an uncertainty of [receiving an account] suspension, do we say that he shall go and be suspended? This comes to teach us that anyone whose heart is righteous shall [better] not speak of them. The time of answer acceptance: They taught a general rule in Maryland: Any answer which does not contain examination and inquiry, we put it on hold, [that is,] we do not accept it, but we do not delete it. Shmuel said: But we have a teaching that the time of answer acceptance is a twenty-four hour period of time doubled.

אמר ליה רבות בריה דמחשבות כי קתני מעת לעת כפולה היכא דאית ביה חקירה ודרישה אבל היכא דלית ליה כולי עלמא לא פליגי דתולין אמר אברהם בן יצחק ואמרי לה יוזר בן שייקס בן פיאב בן ניאן בן אעון ואמרי לה משום עזרא מעיקרא כל מאן דבעי לקבולי תיובתא אזל וקבל מאחר שיצאו הטרולין חזרו ותקנו שלא יהו מקבלין התשובה אלא מעת לעת כפולה:

Rabot Brei DeMachashavot said to him: When we learnt [that the time of anwer acceptance is] a twenty-four hour period of time doubled, [only] where it contains examination and inquiry, however, if it does not contain [examination and inquiry] all do not disagree that we put it on hold. Avraham Ben Yitzchak said, and some say it  was User Ben Six Ben Five Ben Nine Ben One and some say from Ezra: Originally, anyone who wanted to accept an answer, went and accepted it. After the trolls went out [the mods] reconvended and enacted that [Yodeyans] shall not accept the answer unless a twenty-four hour period of time doubled [has elapsed].

אמר רב מנחם אמר דני בר שר אמר דן משום זקן אחד וסבא הלל שמיה דבי המבקש אמרו ויוט אינו אלא תיפלה בעלמא והתנן רבי דובל אומר השאול מתוך ששואל לשם ויוט בא לידי לשמה אחיכו עליה
אמר להו אלקס גברא רבה אמר מילתא לא תחיכו עליה וא"כ אלמה תנן וצוה לה ואמר לה (אי סבירא ליה בא לידי לשמה צוה למה לי) אמר להו רב דניאל לא אמר רבי דובל אלא אמירה ומתוך גדולת תורתו שנו לה בלשון צוה תניא ויוט אינו אלא מלשון וי"ו הבא להוסיף כל טוב שנאמר (משלי כ"א) רדף צדקה וחסד ימצא חיים צדקה וכבוד:
הדרן עלך כיצד שאולין וסליקא לה מסכת יודעין

Rav Menachem said [in the name of] Dani bar Schoer [in the name of] Dan from a certain old man whose name is SabbaHillel: They have said in the academy of Mevaqesh: A vote is only a mere frivolity. Have we not learned in a Mishnah: Rabbi Double says: One who asks [a question] through asking for the purpose of votes, he will come to [ask] for its own sake. They laughed [upon hearing] this statement. Alex said to them: A great man said [this statement], you shall not laugh upon him. If so, why have we learnt in [our] Mishnah ‘And he commanded her, and he said to her’ (if he indeed holds [that one is able] to come [to asking] for its own sake, why do I need it to say ‘and he commanded her’). Rav Dniel said to them: Rabbi Double said [this statement] only by way of saying, [however], on account of the greatness of his Torah [scholarship], they taught the Mishnah using the language of ‘commanded’. We have learnt in a Baraita: The word vote is from the same language of the letter ‘vav’ which only comes to add on all goodness, as it says (Mishlei 21) One who chases charity and kindness will surely find life, charity, righteousness and honor.

WE SHALL RETURN TO YOU KEITZAD SHOALIN AND MASECHET YODEYAN.

Comment: You completely got me on this one. Where is this from?

Comment: This is going to take me forever to learn.

Comment: If anybody finds this at all intelligible  or entertaining, I am surprised at how easy this was to write - if it is not at all that, I am not surprised this was way too easy to write. Also, I kind of was the Rashi (ie filling in the missing parts) as I wrote it, so there may be some parts that can’t be understood- but I tried to make it readable somewhat. Gluten chodesh

Comment: Important question: which דניאל is ר׳ דניאל?

Comment: I thought I also put in a דניאל בר אעף if not then I keep silent

Comment: I'm getting about half? of that.  I hope that mention in the mishna is a good thing and not a bad thing but I can't tell. :-)

Comment: I thought you were being מחמיר  @monica

Comment: How dare you throw shade at the [original Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex). אל תזכר לנו עונות ראשונים

Comment: Very well done. My only critique is that the final paragraph feels like you wanted to get the rest of the active users in and needed to cram them in somewhere; overall, you did a great job with this.

Comment: Well, these are actually forms that appear in the Gemara btw@donielf

Comment: What shade did you think was being thrown

Comment: @Daniel I think he’s referring to me, since [I’m the only one of us with “semicha”](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73120/the-5th-commandment-who-should-be-financially-supported-first-children-or-pa/73125#comment220356_73125).

Comment: Seems to me whoever edits Rashi first, wins

Comment: Some continuity issues with the translation

Comment: There must be something missing.  The mishna you quote says that one moderator commanded another in a matter of site policy, and the g'mara does not say otherwise. If true, this would call the integrity of site moderation into question.  Just as one judge on a *beit din* does not command another how to rule, one moderator does not command another!  All moderators, like all members of a *beit din*, are equal in authority, even if they are not equal in learning.

Comment: @Monica עיין לקמן If so, why have we learnt in [our] Mishnah ‘And he commanded her, and he said to her’ (if he indeed holds [that one is able] to come [to asking] for its own sake, why do I need it to say ‘and he commanded her’). Rav Dniel said to them: Rabbi Double said [this statement] only by way of saying, [however], on account of the greatness of his Torah [scholarship], they taught the Mishnah using the language of ‘commanded’.

Comment: Gemara seems to be saying that the commanding was not literal

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I'll admit I am having trouble with that part of the *g'mara*, but it sounds to me like the commanding has something to do with the greatness of his scholarship?  Or maybe fasting makes me light-headed and I should review this again tomorrow.

Comment: [Don’t rely that all my logic is sound! I didn’t think that hard through all the steps! But,] if I understand your problem with the Mishnah correctly, the Gemara answers that he did not command her at all but since he was such a great scholar they told over the incident in an honorable way. I didn’t see any meforshim saying that- it’s my own pshat. @MonicaCellio

Comment: Oh, I see.  It's quite possible that those who told over the incident did not know the details of site moderation and therefore were unaware that they might be raising an unwarranted doubt.  That must be it; they certainly would not knowingly raise such questions.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the Peirush Rashi on that (please feel free to add, I have actual work to do now, but I'll leave it as a community wiki answer):

> משנה: כיצד שאולין את היודעין רבי דובל אומר שואלין על התורה הנביאים וכתובים רבי יצחק אומר אף על ספרים החיצונים אמר לו רבי דובל לא אם אמרת על ספרים החיצונים אין לדבר סוף רבי משהה העיד על מוניכא שבקשה להוציא כל דברי ספרים החיצונים וצוה לה רבי דובל ואמר לה בכל יום דנין את הזכאי ואת חיב על ידי ויוט ואין נותנין הכלל על ספרים החיצונים שנאמר (קבלת יב) בני וגו׳ עשות ספרים הרבה:

Rashi:
ה"ג **כיצד שואלין את [היודענין](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1763/16354)**
**על התורה** - אין זה [עלהתורה](http://alhatorah.org) באינטרנט, אלא עלהתורה אחר
**רבי משהה** - דהוה בן מאתים ועשר שנים

> גמרא: למה לי למתני כיצד שאולין את היודעין ליתני כיצד שאולין קמ״ל טעמא דשאולין את היודעין הא לאו הכי שאולין אף על העכו״ם פשיטא הקמ״ל דהשתא הוא דאקרי יודעין הא נפק מדוכתיה לדוכתא אחרינא התם נמי איקרי יודעין קמ״ל:
>
> רבי דובל אומר וכו: מאי טעמיה דרבי דובל כדתנן אמרו היודעין לא ירדו אבותינו למצרים אלא כדי לקבל את התורה ואם אין אנו מקיימין אותה מוטב לנו לעבוד אותם בפרך השתא דקאמר תורה שבכתב תורה שבעל פה מנא ליה מנא ליה כדקאמרן אמר אלקס סבר רבי דובל מאי תורה בין תורה שבעל פה בין תורה שבכתב אי הכי הנביאים וכתובים למה לי לתני תורה ואנא ידענא תורה שבכתב והנביאים וכתובים בכלל צריכא כיון דתורה שבעל פה בכלל לא ניחא ליה לתנא למתני ביה תרתי ולתני תורה שבכתב ותורה שבעל פה וליליף הנביאים וכתובים מיניה חד מן חד יליף תרי מן חד לא יליף:

**סבר רבי דובל** - בכמה מקומות אחרות בש"ס, כמו [לגבי בל תוסיף](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76645/does-the-torah-prohibition-to-not-add-or-subtract-from-the-mitzvot-also-apply-to/76646#76646) ואחרים.

> אמר רב שלום אלקס איהו קמייתא דהדר לא ואמאי נפק קמייתא בתר דנחת למהוי אלימא מן בין חבריא שדרו גזירפטי האי מבני חילא למיהב ליה תלת מאה רבוא דהבא ולא ליהדר טפי לבי היודעין ולא קבלה מיניה בתר הכי נפק קלא מן הרמנא דמלכא ארישיה למקטל ביה ערק וסבר מטמר נפשיה אזל טשא בי מדרשא ואוקי התם ויליף וגריס להו אורייתא יומא חדא אידכר האי עלמא דבי יודעין וסבר למימר אנא לית אנא יכיל למהדר בהו אלא אית לי גבאי האי גברא רבא ואיהו צורבא מרבנן ונפק אלקס בתרייתא תותי שמיה דידיה דקמייתא:
>
> תניא אלו הן ספרים החיצונים ספרי לעז ספרי מדינת ישראל ספרי מומרים בעי רב גרשון האי דקאמר רבי דובל אין לדבר סוף הא קחזינן דאיכא אמר ליה רבות אימא סיפא אין נותנין הכלל על ספרים החיצונים אלמא הדר ביה רבי דובל:

**ספרי לעז וכו.** ברייתא זו סותרת למה שהבאנו לעיל דהיו ספרי לשון הקודש, ספרי היסטוריה ועם ישראל, וספרי ארץ ישראל:
"This question does not appear to be about Judaism within the scope defined in the help center. Note that not all questions about the Hebrew language, about history or news of the Jewish people, about Jewish individuals, or about the State of Israel are necessarily about Judaism."

> דרש עמם בר בלאח כתיב (אסתר א) וישלח ספרים וכתיב (אסתר ט) וישלח ספרים מה הכא ספרים ואל עם ועם כלשונו אף התם ספרים אל כל היהודים לומר לך דהלכה כרבי יצחק ולא יחסר מעם היהודים:
>
> בעי עאל מהו לדבר אבל לא לשאול מהו להשיב על הנשאלין מהו לתקן מהו להכשיר הפסול מהו להוציא בעל מום מהו לאסור הטריפה מהו לאסור המותר תיקו:
>
> ת״ר אין בין רבי דובל לרבי יצחק אלא שלשה דברים בלבד ואלו הן כינויי לעז שיחה גזולה וזמן קבלת התשובה והתנן רבי יצחק אומר אף ספרים החיצונים ואמרינן מאי ספרים החיצונים כל ספרים החיצונים אלמא איכא טובא בינייהו לא קשיא הא ספרא הא מילתא קתני מיהת כינויי לעז שיחה גזולה וזמן קבלת התשובה כינויי לעז סברי רבנן למימר משלי העכו״ם נינהו עד שבא עמם בר בלאח מארץ רחוקה ואמר קבלה בידי אין כינויי לעז אלא דיבורי בני אדם וכל חרד לבו לא ידבר בהם שיחה גזולה ומי איכא דפליג עליה דרבי דובל אין רבי יואל בן קירא היא דאמר מה שיחה שאינה גזולה יש בה חוששין לספק גזולה מחמת הטבע ושרי שיחה גזולה דוודאי גזולה עאכ״ו דשרי מתיב אלקס ותסברא גזולה דספק נידוי ספק אינו נידוי מי אמרינן ליזיל ולשמתיה קמ״ל כל חרד לבו לא ידבר בהם וזמן קבלת התשובה כלל אמרו במרילנד כל תשובה שאין בה דרישה וחקירה תולין לא מקבלין ולא מוחקין אמר שמואל הא נקטנין זמן קבלת התשובה מעת לעת כפולה אמר ליה רבות בר מחשבות כי קתני מעת לעת כפולה היכא דאית ביה חקירה ודרישה אבל היכא דלית ליה כולי עלמא לא פליגי דתולין אמר אברהם בן יצחק ואמרי לה יוזר בן שייקס בן פיאב בן ניאן בן אעון ואמרי לה משום עזרא מעיקרא כל מאן דבעי לקבולי תיובתא אזל וקבל מאחר שיצאו הטרולין חזרו ותקנו שלא יהו מקבלין התשובה אלא מעת לעת כפולה:
>
> אמר רב מנחם אמר דני בר שר אמר דן משום זקן אחד וסבא הלל שמיה דבי המבקש אמרו ויוט אינו אלא תיפלה בעלמא והתנן רבי דובל אומר השאול מתוך ששואל לשם ויוט בא לידי לשמה אחיכו עליה אמר להו אלקס גברא רבה אמר מילתא לא תחיכו עליה וא"כ אלמה תנן וצוה לה ואמר לה (אי סבירא ליה בא לידי לשמה צוה למה לי) אמר להו רב דניאל לא אמר רבי דובל אלא אמירה ומתוך גדולת תורתו שנו לה בלשון צוה תניא ויוט אינו אלא מלשון וי"ו הבא להוסיף כל טוב שנאמר (משלי כ"א) רדף צדקה וחסד ימצא חיים צדקה וכבוד:

Answer (score 2):

Mi Yodea is in the Megilla: ומי יודע אם לעת כזאת הגעת למלכות.

So one must respond as if in the presence of royalty.  I guess the guidelines for *Shemona Esray* would apply.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15061/759