# Hagaddah with Kabbalistic incorporation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, passover-seder-hagada, mysticism-kabbalah

I'd like to view the Haggadah in light of Kabbalistic writings, such as the Zohar and subsequent works. Have there been any publications, whether in recent years or not, which cull together or explain different portions of the Haggadah with incorporation of these texts and idea?

Comment: Dr. Shmuel, how strong is your Hebrew?

Comment: @YaacovDeane In tow with my Aramaic: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100253/16706 :)

Comment: In that case, in the context of your question I would highly recommend the Hagaddah of Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov as your primary source. His text is highly authoritative and his explanations are detailed enough that you will have a solid grasp intellectually of what is being discussed.

Comment: Here's a link for a recently printed version: https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=5994&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Comment: You may be interested in Yad Mitzrayim from R' Yitzchak Issac Chaver

Comment: הגדה של המגיד מקוזניץ

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/21558

Comment: [Siddur Ha’geonim Ve’ha’mekubalim ve’ha’hassidim - Haggadah Shel Pesah](https://hebrewbooks.org/21796).

Comment: @Oliver Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Vilna Gaon's Hagada [translated](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899064482.html) by Artscroll includes many kabbalistic concepts, as well as the Hagada of the Alshich by [Feldheim](https://www.feldheim.com/the-alshich-haggadah-1) as the Alshich was "an early mentor of Rav Chaim Vital" ([who was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_ben_Joseph_Vital) the leading disciple of the Arizal)

Answer (score 1):

If your Hebrew is up to it, you could give this hagada by the Ben Ish Chai a try https://seforimcenter.com/Haggadah---Ben-Ish-Chai__p-12857.aspx , or, for those with fluent Hebrew and who are accustomed to using Kavanot, this one with both Rahash kavanot and the writings of the Arizal: https://www.judaicaplace.com/haggadah-shel-pesach-haarizal-hardcover/harzl/